# Garry's Mod Websockets with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, garrys-mod

First, sorry for my English, but I'm french.

I need your help because my team and me actually work on **"Multi-Server"** in Garry's Mod, I explain :
We have 4 servers, and we wan't to make comunicate servers, so I have thinking about using **Node JS / Socket.io** to create a server (At first, I'm a Web Developper), and all the Garry's Mod server be a client, but I don't know if it's possible to connect a ***Gmod server to a NodeJS server***, So I ask you if you had an API or something else to create that.

Thanks Before for your answers, Cordially Matspyder.

Comment: Websockets are kind of special. I don't know much about Garry's Mod (besides that it exists), but I would consider support for normal sockets to be far more likely than support for websockets.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple C++ modules that lets you create regular sockets in Garry's Mod ([Bromsock](https://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1393640), [GLSock](https://www.facepunch.com/threads/1136961)) however none of them support websockets so you will have to use the [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) Node.js module.

If you wish to have a practical example of a system running on Node.js and Bromsock you can have a look at my Steam chat bot's source code: [FoxedBot](https://github.com/Starfox64/FoxedBot).